# PHP post не видит переменные

Tags: php, post

моя первая программа, не могу понять почему не работает

Это HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TesT</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
<body>
    <h2>Введи свои данные:</h2>
    <form action="display.php" method="post">
        <p>Введите имя: <input type="text" name="firstname" /></p>
        <p>Введите фамилию: <input type="text" name="lastname" /></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    
    $name = $_POST["firstname"];
    $surname = $_POST["lastname"]; 
   
    
    echo "Ваше имя: <b>".$name . " " . $surname . "</b>";
?>
```

Получаю вот такую ошибку

```
stderr: PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "firstname" in C:\Users\user\Desktop\phpGides\display.php on line 3
PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "lastname" in C:\Users\user\Desktop\phpGides\display.php on line 4
```

Comment: несколько странно видеть тут `stderr:`. Что там в целом в `print_r($_POST)`  проверьте что `name` у инпутов с корректными латинскими буквами

Comment: Проверил. Все корректно

Comment: Проверьте настройки сервера. Вероятнее всего, программа которая проксирует запрос(apache/nginx) не передает параметры запроса

Comment: вы же скрипт вызываете отправкой формы, а не через консоль `php display.php`, правда?

Comment: Да конечно. на сервере, через отправку формы с данными

Comment: Если в браузере в консоле разработчика посмотреть display.php то там при отправке формы в разделе Payload появляются заполненные данные с формы

Comment: покажите полностью display.php